# IIS 8.5 - 500 Error when serving Static Content (PNGs/JS/etc)

Tags: c#, windows, iis, asp.net-web-api, configuration

## Background

I am deploying a C# MVC/WebApi-based web application to a new platform (Windows 2012 R2 Standard - IIS 8.5). The web application itself responds normally with no errors with the core code, connectivity to the database, etc.

## Problem

When any client via a web browser accesses the web application all static files (CSS/Font/JS/Image) cannot be displayed, a **500 Internal Server Error** status code is returned for the requests for these files.

However, if the CSS/JS files are minified and bundles via C# bundling functionality these requests are returned correctly. Fonts and images still do not display.

## Troubleshooting

Verified the following:

- **Directory Browsing** and **Static Content** features are enabled under Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Common HTTP Features
- StaticFile is defined as a HandlerMpping for the web application with the following settings:

  - Path: *
  - State: Enabled
  - Path Type: File or Folder
  - Handler: StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule
  - Entry Type: Inherited
- The Application Pool user for the web application has read access to the directory, subdirectories and all files.

## Reference

### web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="1000" maxQueryStringLength="10000" targetFramework="4.5.2" requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" enableVersionHeader="false" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
    <trace writeToDiagnosticsTrace="false" enabled="false" pageOutput="false" localOnly="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <httpCompression directory="[[REDACTED]]\IISContentCompression" minFileSizeForComp="1024">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Custom">
      <!-- Catch IIS 404 error due to paths that exist but shouldn't be served (e.g. /controllers, /global.asax) or IIS request filtering (e.g. bin, web.config, app_code, app_globalresources, app_localresources, app_webreferences, app_data, app_browsers) -->
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" path="/notfound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" path="/error" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <staticContent>
      <!-- Set expire headers to 30 days for static content-->
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" />
      <!-- use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html -->
      <remove fileExtension=".css" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css" />
      <remove fileExtension=".js" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".rss" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".html" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <remove fileExtension=".xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8" />
      <!-- HTML5 Audio/Video mime types-->
      <remove fileExtension=".mp3" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ogg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ogv" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm" />
      <!-- Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad -->
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svgz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <!-- HTML4 Web font mime types -->
      <!-- Remove default IIS mime type for .eot which is application/octet-stream -->
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttc" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".crx" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension" />
      <remove fileExtension=".xpi" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall" />
      <remove fileExtension=".safariextz" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <!-- Flash Video mime types-->
      <remove fileExtension=".flv" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv" />
      <remove fileExtension=".f4v" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <!-- Assorted types -->
      <remove fileExtension=".ico" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp" />
      <remove fileExtension=".htc" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component" />
      <remove fileExtension=".vcf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
      <remove fileExtension=".torrent" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent" />
      <remove fileExtension=".cur" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon" />
      <remove fileExtension=".webapp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="X-Powered-By" value="[[REDACTED]]" />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="20000" maxQueryString="1073741824" maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PP" connectionString="[[REDACTED]]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <location path="[[REDACTED]]">
    <system.web>
      <!--<authentication mode="None"/>-->
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <!--<anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />-->
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="ApplicationReportingDB" />
    </root>
    <appender name="ApplicationReportingDB" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="[[REDACTED]]" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO ErrorLog ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="[[REDACTED]]" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{CustomColumn}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <location path="[[REDACTED]]">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Is there any more error information associated with that 500 code? Is something showing up in the error logs?

Comment: @tattarrattat No, just the error code with no information. I added `<customErrors mode="Off"/>` to no avail.

Comment: I wish I had more to tell you, but I had a problem with this a few years ago due to mime type restrictions